# Space dashes such that they ignore the contents beneath underbraces

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, underbrace

I'm trying to break down words into morphemes and display them in a concise way.

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}

% ... etc ...

d. not compound, polymorphemic:
$\underbrace{\text{doubt}}_{\text{free root}}\: - \:\underbrace{\text{less}}_{\text{free derivational suffix}}\: - \:\underbrace{\text{ly}}_{\text{bound derivational suffix}}$
```

I've got the underbraces working, however the dashes in between appear a bit
haphazardly because they're taking into account the width of the content below the underbrace, which is usually but not always larger than the content above it. How do I somehow force the dashes to appear centrally between the content above the underbrace, ignoring everything below it? In the image below, the dash between `less` and `ly` looks about right, but the one between `doubt` and `less` is too far to the left because the content below `doubt` is smaller than the content below `less`.

[image: results]

The desired result:

[image: desire]

Comment: So you are effectively looking for something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhCuK.png).

Comment: @Werner Yes, that's exactly it. Apologies for not knowing the right terms to phrase this well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to do some measurements, you can set the dashes (`\textminus` below) between the elements without problem. `\tmpbox` is used to store the entire construction *without* the dashes, while `\tmplenA`, `\tmplenB` and `\tmplenC` are used to measure the widest element between the base and the underbrace text for the first, second and third "term," respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newsavebox{\tmpbox}
\newlength{\tmplenA}
\newlength{\tmplenB}
\newlength{\tmplenC}

\begin{document}

d. not compound, polymorphemic:
\[
  % Capture width of entire structure
  \savebox{\tmpbox}{$
    \underbrace{\text{doubt\strut}}_{\text{free root}}
    \quad% \hspace{1em}
    \underbrace{\text{less\strut}}_{\text{free derivational suffix}}
    \quad% \hspace{1em}
    \underbrace{\text{ly\strut}}_{\text{bound derivational suffix}}
  $}
  % Set entire structure in a zero-width, left-aligned box
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{\tmpbox}}
  \settowidth{\tmplenA}{\text{\scriptsize free root}}% Widest element of first "term"
  \settowidth{\tmplenB}{\text{\scriptsize free derivational suffix}}% Widest element of second "term"
  \settowidth{\tmplenC}{\text{\scriptsize bound derivational suffix}}% Widest element of third "term"
  % Set box of width matching original structure (left-aligned)
  \makebox[\wd\tmpbox][l]{%
    \hspace{0.5\tmplenA}% Skip to middle of first "term"
    \makebox[\dimexpr0.5\tmplenA+1em+0.5\tmplenB]{\textminus}% Set \textminus halfway between first and second "term"
    \makebox[\dimexpr0.5\tmplenB+1em+0.5\tmplenC]{\textminus}% Set \textminus halfway between second and third "term"
  }
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was initially scared by this but it's actually more generalizable than I realized, even for a beginner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to measure the parts (top and bottom) and print the dash in between items with an offset that depends on the widths of the items at the left and the right. Here I use a zero-width box, so it doesn't add space; the separation between items is one em, so the en-dash fits well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}

\NewDocumentCommand{\textubrace}{mm}{%
  \ensuremath{\underbrace{\text{#1\strut}}_{\text{#2\vphantom{ly}}}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\morphemes}{m}
 {% #1 = {doubt}{free root},{less}{free derivational suffix},{ly}{bound derivational suffix}
  \naiveai_morphemes:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__naive_morphemes_items_seq % the items
\seq_new:N \l__naive_morphemes_top_seq % the widths of the top items
\seq_new:N \l__naive_morphemes_bot_seq % the widths of the bottom items

\dim_new:N \l__naive_morphemes_tmp_dim

\cs_new_protected:Nn \naiveai_morphemes:n
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__naive_morphemes_items_seq { #1 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__naive_morphemes_top_seq
  \seq_clear:N \l__naive_morphemes_bot_seq
  % store the half-widths
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__naive_morphemes_items_seq \__naiveai_morphemes_measure:n
  % check that the bottom widths aren't less than the corresponding top width
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__naive_morphemes_top_seq
   {
    \dim_compare:nT { \seq_item:Nn \l__naive_morphemes_bot_seq { ##1 } < ##2 }
     {
      \seq_set_item:Nnn \l__naive_morphemes_bot_seq { ##1 } { ##2 }
     }
   }
  % typeset
  \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l__naive_morphemes_items_seq - 1 }
   {
    % the item
    \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \textubrace { \seq_item:Nn \l__naive_morphemes_items_seq { ##1 } }
    % half space
    \nobreak
    \skip_horizontal:n { 0.5em }
    % the dash; first compute the offset
    \dim_set:Nn \l__naive_morphemes_tmp_dim
     {
      (
       \seq_item:Nn \l__naive_morphemes_bot_seq { ##1 } % left bot width
       -
       \seq_item:Nn \l__naive_morphemes_top_seq { ##1 } % left top width
      )
      -
      (
       \seq_item:Nn \l__naive_morphemes_bot_seq { ##1 + 1 } % right bot width
       -
       \seq_item:Nn \l__naive_morphemes_top_seq { ##1 + 1 } % right top width
      )
     }
    % the dash, suitably offset 
    \hbox_to_zero:n
     {
      \hss
      \dim_compare:nTF { \l__naive_morphemes_tmp_dim > 0pt }
       { -- \skip_horizontal:n { \l__naive_morphemes_tmp_dim } }
       { \skip_horizontal:n { -\l__naive_morphemes_tmp_dim } -- } 
      \hss
     }
    % half space
    \nobreak
    \skip_horizontal:n { 0.5em }
   }
  % the last item
  \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \textubrace { \seq_item:Nn \l__naive_morphemes_items_seq { -1 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__naiveai_morphemes_measure:n
 {
  \__naiveai_morphemes_measure_both:nn #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__naiveai_morphemes_measure_both:nn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l__naive_morphemes_top_seq { \dim_eval:n { (\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box)/2 } }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \ensuremath { \scriptstyle \text { #2 } } }
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l__naive_morphemes_bot_seq { \dim_eval:n { (\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box)/2 } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\morphemes{
  {doubt}{free root},
  {less}{free derivational suffix},
  {ly}{bound derivational suffix}
}
\\[2ex]
\morphemes{
  {xxxxxxx}{x},
  {abc}{abcde},
  {yyyyy}{yyyyyyy}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]